# Variables in a SQL table update for a discord.py bot

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, discord.py

I am building a Discord bot (using discord.py) that is connected to a PostgreSQL database.

I have multiple tables with all the table names stored in a list of strings called `TableNames`.

When I use the table name directly, like so:

```
await self.bot.ARC.execute("UPDATE utah SET utah = $1 WHERE user_id = $2", True, message.author.id)
```

everything works fine.

But when I try to set the table name as a variable, like so:

```
wait self.bot.ARC.execute("UPDATE $1 SET $2 = True WHERE user_id = $3", 'utah', 'utah', message.author.id)
```

I get an error saying I have a syntax error on `$1`.

Can I set the table name as a variable and not get the syntax error? If so, how can I do so?

Comment: You can't pass a table name as query parameter, because your RDBMS must be able to *prepare* the query from the query string before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list of strings, `TableNames`, contains safe input (or doesn't contain any user input), you can simply format the query string directly in Python for the relevant substrings, e.g. table name, before you pass it to `execute`.

Otherwise, you'll likely need to perform a [dynamic query/command using PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 0):

For now I have looped around my problem with a heavy list :

```
user = await self.bot.ARC.fetch(Globals.FetchARCDB[Globals.Dinosaurs.index(Dino)], member.id)
```

with 
`Globals.FetchARCDB[Globals.Dinosaurs.index(Dino)]` equal to `"UPDATE utah SET utah = $1 WHERE user_id = $2"`

This works but needs a very big list that needs to be manually set up (used loops but still very annyoing...)